# nmake syntax error at -e line 1, near "'755' ]"

Tags: nmake

Everytime I try to run nmake on **any package**, it gives me this error:

> syntax error at -e line 1, near "'755' ]" Missing right curly or
>   square bracket at -e line 1, at end of line Execution of -e aborted
>   due to compilation errors.

Does anyone know why this might be?

I believe this answer might be what's happening: [Compiling WWW::Curl on ActivePerl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399399/compiling-wwwcurl-on-activeperl/5425427#5425427)

In my /N output, there's:

> C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Install -e "pm_to_blib({{@ARGV},
>   'blib \lib\auto', q[], '755')"

What's with the {{? I guess this Makefile is just messed up then. The same thing happened when I tried to make Perltidy from source however.

Comment: dmake seems to work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used dmake, and there were no problems with the curly braces.